# If there is a surjection $f\colon X\to Y$, then $|Y|\leq |X|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, axiom-of-choice

If there is an injection $A\to B$, we say that $|A|\leq |B|$.

> **Proposition.** If there exists a surjection $f\colon X\to Y$, then $|Y|\leq |X|$.

The proof goes as follows

> Let $c$ be a choice function for $\mathscr{P}(X)$; since $\{f^{-1}(y)\mid y\in Y\}$ is a partition of $X$, it follows that $y\mapsto c\big(f^{-1}(y)\big)$ is an injection $Y\to X$.

My problem is that I don't know what the domain for $c$ is. A choice function was defined as an object of the form $c\colon \mathscr{A}\to \bigcup\{A_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$ that satisfies $\forall \alpha\in\mathscr{A},\; c(\alpha)\in A_\alpha$. The indexing set ($\mathscr{A}$) is not specified on the proof. What is the domain of $c$? Clearly $f^{-1}(y)$ must be an element of the indexing set. How was the indexation done such that $c(f^{-1}(y))=c(f^{-1}(\gamma))\implies y=\gamma$? This doesn't seem trivial since all we know is that $c(f^{-1}(y))\in A_{f^{-1}(y)}$ (this doesn't say anything about the set $A_{f^{-1}(y)}\subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$).

Comment: The idea of the proof is simple: since $X$ can be surjected onto $Y$, it suffices to pick, for each $y$, one element of $x$ that maps to it.

Comment: The proof says "choice function for $\mathscr{P}(X)$".  Every set of sets can be viewed as a family indexed by itself: the set of indices is the power set of $X$, and the set corresponding to the subset $A$ is $A$ itself. I will note, however, that what they should have is that it is a choice function for the **non-empty** subsets of $X$, not for the full power set (which does not have a choice function because of the empty set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicity, the choice function is $c:\mathcal{P}(X)\to\bigcup\{X: X\in \mathcal{P}(X)\}$, i.e. it picks an element from any subset of $X$.

Injectivity of $c \circ f^{-1}$ follows from the fact that $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(z)$ are disjoint sets whenever $y\neq z$. Thus, $c$ can't pick out a common element from the two sets.

Comment: There is no such choice function. You need to exclude $\varnothing$ from the domain (that's an error in the argument provided).